# How do I make NppExec open Git Bash in its own window?

Tags: windows, git, notepad++, nppexec

I installed the NppExec plugin for Notepad++ to be able to run Git Bash from inside the application, but it runs the script within the built-in console in Notepad++. This makes the colors disappear, and decreasing readability of the status messages.

How do I make NppExec open a new cmd window with Git Bash, with the same working directory as the file I am currently editing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the plugin options for NppExec, mark the `Follow $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)` menu item to make it run the scripts from your current working directory.

[image: Screenshot NppExec plugin menu]

Then, save and execute this script, to make the Git Bash open in a new command line window.

```
cmd /c start "Git Bash" "C:\Progra~2\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i
```